# Oracle instead of trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm getting the error 
`Error(2,67): PLS-00049: bad bind variable OLD.DEPTNAME while executing below trigger` also getting 'enter binds' prompt in SQL developer

```
create or replace trigger emp_Dept_view_trig
instead of update on emp_Dept_view
for each row 
begin
update department set LOCATION  = :NEW.LOCATION  where DEPTNAME:OLD.DEPTNAME;
commit;
end;
```

Comment: DEPTNAME  = :OLD.DEPTNAME

Comment: For prompt of binds please execute: `SET DEFINE OFF` command before compiling trigger;

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_Dept_view_trig
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
   ON emp_Dept_view
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE department
      SET LOCATION = :NEW.LOCATION
    WHERE DEPTNAME=:OLD.DEPTNAME; 
    commit; end;
```